Would you put a possessive pronoun before "destitution" in this sentence?
Would you say this:

This story tells of a young man who asks for his inheritance early, then squanders it in a foreign land, leading to destitution.

or this:

This story tells of a young man who asks for his inheritance early, then squanders it in a foreign land, leading to his destitution.


No, because destitution is a state, not a possession. That's not a rule ("leading to his demise"), but using a pronoun seems unidiomatic.

It sounds idiomatic to me.

@WeatherVane In Google Books, "led to his destitution" is not found but you can find a certain number of "led to their destitution" (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22led%20to%20their%20destitution%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en); then "his destitution" is quite common: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22his%20destitution%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

@WeatherVane We use possessives with a number of states: his death, his enlightenment

@Barmar as I said: 'his demise' but 'his destitution' doesn't sound right to me.

An Ngram count confirms his/their destitution is relatively common. If you insert common adjectives like extreme or abject, the count goes up. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abject+destitution%2Chis+destitution%2Ctheir+destitution%2Cextreme+destitution%2Ctheir+extreme+destitution

But "leading to death" or "leading to enlightenment" are also common, and "leading to confusion" etc. There are standard expressions like "into destitution", "in destitution" - but here I think "lead to" is a phrasal verb not a verb followed by a prepositional phrase. "Destitution" is a general state, not one particular to a person, may be the logic.

Ngrams has no hits for "leading to his destitution" (or her or their). Obviously "leading to destitution" could be replaced with any number of possessives, but still looks like no possessive is better.

These Google ngrams add support to the ' "his destitution" is rare' stance. Stuart is quite right.

In this particular context, using the possessive pronoun sounds perfectly fine; it is even indicated to use it. There is no hiccup:

This story tells of a young man who asks for his inheritance early, then squanders it in a foreign land, leading to his destitution.

The story is about him, therefore it is not out of place to use the possessive his before destitution.
Also, the argument that it is a state and therefore should not be preceded by a possessive does not really stand. In fact, in certain structures the possessive is even necessary, as it is for example in the idiom

much to someone's delight, dismay, disappointment, surprise, etc. (Cambridge)

Here is a very similar example from The treatment of asylum seekers (Great Britain: Parliament: Joint Committee on Human Rights, Andrew Dismore · 2007):

Edward was referred to SWVG on humanitarian grounds by one of Southampton's MPs. He has been in the UK for seven years. Eritrea, his country of origin, will not accept him back because efforts to trace his family have been unsuccessful and therefore he cannot provide the necessary three witnesses to his nationality. In the UK he has worked whenever permitted—for a long time he has not been permitted to work—and about a year ago his meagre savings ran out leading to his destitution.


The Google ngrams linked to in my comment above seem to indicate that 'his destitution' is not too idiomatic. I'd certainly avoid it.

@EdwinAshworth I am not saying it is idiomatic. Just that it is right for this context.
